# How to search for a String pattern?

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I just want to know how to find the specific string pattern in a paragraph using Java. 
The string I want to search is: **AB0002340001**. The string pattern could be:
Two alphabets(that can be any alphabets)+10 digits(that can be of any digit combination).
Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

There you specify patterns using special groups. E.g. "two characters + 10 digits" is:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w{2}\\d{10})");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(inputString);
while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bozho. Code for finding matches didnt work:<code>String pattern = "\\w{2}\\d{10}" boolean matches = str.matches(pattern); </code>.<br/> but code for testing the result of matched patterns is working fine.

Comment: ah ,yes, it's because it tries to match the whole string. I removed that part, as it is irrelevant. If the answer is sufficient, feel free to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

First create pattern:

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w{2}\\d{10}");`

Now you can find for this pattern as following:

`pattern.matcher(str).find()`

Comment: Thanks AlexR. I just want to match exactly the String of type IH0909090909 (2 characters+10 digits) which means code should not even find pattern in the string 'BLAHIH0909090909BLAH'.  <br/>   I tried   <code>  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w{2}\\d{10})");  </code>  but it is not working for above said scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expression
See this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) to know how to use regex in java

Comment: Thanks Abu. I just want to match exactly the String of type IH0909090909 (2 characters+10 digits) which means code should not even find pattern in the string 'BLAHIH0909090909BLAH'. <br/> I tried <code> Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w{2}\\d{10})"); </code> but it is not working for above said scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will need to use the `lookingAt()` method not `matches()` method.